# Why did the first operation with the DOM is much longer than the others?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Written by the same realization in JS and jQuery.
Subsequent manipulation of the DOM practically identical in time, however, the first operation is much more why?

[Javascript source](https://jsfiddle.net/dwfr05bh/)

```
// ES5

// отправка сообщения
function sendMessage(){

  var timerName;
  console.time(timerName);

  var nameUser = 'Максим';
  var currentDate = new Date(); 
  var el = document.querySelector('.send-text');
  var dateTime = currentDate.getHours() + ":" + currentDate.getMinutes() + ":" + currentDate.getSeconds();
  var data = el.value.replace(/\n/g, "<br>"); el.value = "";

  // записываем новый DOM
  document.querySelector('.col-message-list').innerHTML +=   
    '<div class="message-user">' + 
      '<span class="messege-remove label error outline">Удалить</span>' +
      '<p class="name"><samp>' + nameUser + '</samp><span class="time">' + dateTime + '</span></p>' +
      '<div>' +
        data +
      '</div>' +
    '</div>';

  // необходимо повесить событие удаления сообщения, когда добавили новый элемент
  var message = document.querySelectorAll('.messege-remove');
  Array.from(message).forEach(function(el) {
      el.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
         event.target.parentNode.remove();
      });
  });

  console.timeEnd(timerName);
}

// событие клика по кнопке отправки сообщения
document.querySelector('.send-button').addEventListener("click", sendMessage); 
document.querySelector('.send-text').addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
    if (e.ctrlKey && e.keyCode === 13) sendMessage();
});
```

[image]

[jQuery source](https://jsfiddle.net/LLy9wt9q/)

```
// ES6+
'use strict';

// отправка сообщения
function sendMessage(){

  let timerName;
  console.time(timerName);

  // получаем текст из textarea
  let nameUser = 'Максим';
  let el = $('.send-text');
  let data = el.val().replace(/\n/g, "<br>"); el.val('');
  let currentDate = new Date(); 
  let dateTime = currentDate.getHours() + ":" + currentDate.getMinutes() + ":" + currentDate.getSeconds();

  // записываем новый DOM
  $('.col-message-list').append(` 
    <div class="message-user">
      <span class="messege-remove label error outline">Удалить</span>
      <p class="name"><samp>${nameUser}</samp><span class="time">${dateTime}</span></p>
      <div>
        ${data}
      </div>
    </div>
  `);

  // необходимо повесить событие удаления сообщения, когда добавили новый элемент
  $('.messege-remove').unbind('click').on('click', e => e.target.parentNode.remove());

  console.timeEnd(timerName);
}

// событие клика по кнопке отправки сообщения
$('.send-button').on('click', sendMessage);
$('.send-text').on('keydown', e => { if (e.ctrlKey && e.keyCode == 13) sendMessage(); });
```

[image]

However, when I became self add more number of messages in pure JavaScript code began to work much worse with a larger number of DOM-elements

Comment: Resetting `innerHTML` like that is pretty expensive (and destructive). I believe jQuery parses the supplied HTML and appends the newly created node(s) to the existing DOM... instead of destroying and rewriting it. You could do the same thing by just creating the nodes yourself.

Comment: The jQuery selector or the `document.querySelector()` reads each time the whole DOM in order to find matches to that selector. So it is really ineffecient if you need it multiple times. For this, it's better to use angular (templates), there it only once requires to read the whole DOM at initialization. In combination with rxjs you will have a nice and smooth way to get the job effeciently done.

Comment: @canon, what is "Resetting innerHTML"? Please, where to read about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just going to use this post as a placeholder for optimizations to the above.

**JQuery**

I was able to shave off 1/3 of the initial and subsequent "sendMessage()" execution runtime by using delegate events instead of bind/unbind:

```
$('.col-message-list').on('click', '.messege-remove', e => e.target.parentNode.remove());
```

Add the above outside of the "sendMessage" function and remove the bind/unbind method from within the "sendMessage" function.

Was able to shave another 2/3rds of the initial and subsequent runtime by cheating a little bit and using "requestAnimationFrame". [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Aliester/LLy9wt9q/21/)

Noticed that the "click" event triggering the "sendMessage" runs about 5 times faster than the combination key trigger on "keydown",